# Why does an uint64_t needs more memory than 2 uint32_t's when used in a class? And how to prevent this?

Tags: c++, class, size, uint64

I have made the following code as an example.

```
#include <iostream>

struct class1
{

    uint8_t     a;
    uint8_t     b;
    uint16_t    c;
    uint32_t    d;
    uint32_t    e;

    uint32_t    f;
    uint32_t    g;
};

struct class2
{

    uint8_t     a;
    uint8_t     b;
    uint16_t    c;
    uint32_t    d;
    uint32_t    e;

    uint64_t    f;
};

int main(){
    std::cout << sizeof(class1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(class2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(uint64_t) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(uint32_t) << std::endl;
}
```

prints

```
20
24
8
4
```

So it's fairly simple to see that one uint64_t is as large as two uint32_t's, Why would class 2 have 4 extra bytes, if they are the same except for the substitution of two uint32_t's for an uint64_t.

Comment: Alignment. `class2` needs to be 8-byte aligned. `class1` doesn't.

Comment: This basically just happens because of how you build your classes. As `uint64_t` has to be aligned the compiler needs to throw in 4 bytes of padding in `class2` (after the variable `e`)

Comment: You can also rearrange the structures to have the fields in descending order of size, then the padding issues won't appear since the larger fields are already on a nice byte alignment, and will transfer that to the fields of less size.

Comment: @UnholySheep Yeah, well, that's true, and sometimes fields of different sizes could benefit from being grouped together from a readable point of view as well, but it is an easy way to know that there will be no weird padding effects, for example when copying memory from one place to another.

Comment: Try removing `e` from both and compare ;) That should move `f` to 8B-aligned adress, so, no padding needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it was pointed out, this is due to [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

To prevent this, you may use

```
#pragma pack(1)

class ... {

};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

It tells your compiler to align not to 8 bytes, but to one byte. The pop command switches it off (this is very important, since if you do that in the header and somebody includes your header, very weird errors may occur)

Comment: The question is "why is it happening," not "what should I do about it." Mentioning `#pragma pack` is indeed on topic, but you should also explain (and not just link to) the actual cause.

Comment: Alternatively he can change the order of variables in his class definition.

Comment: Also, `#pragma pack` is compiler-specific (even though it may be widely supported)

Comment: I was refering to the question from the title: what should be done to prevent this. I've updated the answer to account for that.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does an uint64_t needs more memory than 2 uint32_t's when used in a class?

The reason is padding due to alignment requirements.

On most 64-bit architectures uint8_t has an alignment requirement of 1, uint16_t has an alignment requirement of 2, uint32_t has an alignment requirement of 4 and uint64_t has an alignment requirement of 8. The compiler must ensure that all members in a structure are correctly aligned and that the size of a structure is a multiple of it's overall alignment requirement. Furthermore the compiler is not allowed to re-order members.

So your structs end up laid out as follows

```
struct class1
{
    
    uint8_t     a; //offset 0
    uint8_t     b; //offset 1
    uint16_t    c; //offset 2
    uint32_t    d; //offset 4
    uint32_t    e; //offset 8
    
    uint32_t    f; //offset 12
    uint32_t    g; //offset 16
}; //overall alignment requirement 4, overall size 20.

struct class2
{
    
    uint8_t     a; //offset 0
    uint8_t     b; //offset 1
    uint16_t    c; //offset 2
    uint32_t    d; //offset 4
    uint32_t    e; //offset 8
    // 4 bytes of padding because f has an alignment requirement of 8
    uint64_t    f; //offset 16
}; //overall alignment requirement 8, overall size 24
```

> And how to prevent this?

Unfortunately there is no good general solution.

Sometimes it is possible to reduce the amount of padding by re-ordering fields, but that doesn't help in your case. It just moves the padding around in the structure. A structure with a field requiring 8 byte alignment will always have a size that is a multiple of 8. Therefore no matter how much you rearrange the fields your structure will always have a size of at least 24.

You can use compiler-specific features such as `#pragma pack` or `__attribute((packed))` to force the compiler to pack the structure more tightly than normal alignment requirements would allow. However, as well as limiting portability, this creates a problem when taking the address of a member or binding a reference to the member. The resulting pointer or reference may not satisfy the alignment requirements and therefore may not be safe to use.

Different compilers vary in how they handle this problem. From some playing around on godbolt.

- g++ 9 through 11 will refuse to bind a reference to a packed member and give a warning when taking the address.
- clang 4 through 11 will give a warning when taking the address, but will silently bind a reference and pass that reference across a compilation unit boundary.
- Clang 3.9 and earlier will take the address and bind a reference silently.
- g++ 8 and earlier and clang 3.9 and earlier (down to the oldest version on godbolt) will also refuse to bind a reference, but will take the address with no warning.
- icc will bind a pointer or take the address without producing any warnings in either case (though to be fair intel processors support unaligned access in hardware).

Answer (score 0):

The rule for alignment (on x86 and x86_64) is generally to *align a variable on it's size*.

In other words, 32-bit variables are aligned on 4 bytes, 64-bit variables on 8 bytes, etc.

The offset of `f` is 12, so in case of `uint32_t f` no padding is needed, but when `f` is an `uint64_t`, 4 bytes of padding are added to get `f` to align on 8 bytes.

For this reason it is better to **order data members from largest to smallest**. Then there wouldn't be any need for padding or packing (except possibly at the end of the structure).

Comment: Unfortunately the last sentence of this answer is not true. As well as aligning the fields within a structure the compiler must ensure that the overall size of the structure is a multiple of it's alignment requirement. Otherwise arrays would not work properly. So while re-ordering fields can sometimes be helpful, it is of no help in the case of the structure given in this question.

Comment: @plugwash thanks for spotting an error, is fixed now.